# Why is the onClose event not sent for Webkit notifications in Chrome on Mountain Lion when the notification is dismissed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, notifications, osx-mountain-lion

I am using Webkit notifications on my web page to notify users of an update in the page (which updates regularly using AJAX).
I am using the prefixed *webkitNotifications* rather than the non-prefixed version to maintain as much backwards compatibility as possible.
I create a notification, retain a reference to it in an element's data (using jQuery), add an *onClose* handler function to it, then show it.
The notification appears in the notification centre as it should, and functions properly.
If I attach an *onClick* handler to it, that functions as expected also.
However, when I dismiss the notification (either by clicking close if I have it as an alert, or by clearing it in the notification centre if it is just a banner) my *onClose* handler is not called in Chrome. I still have a reference to the notification on my web page, and if I call the cancel method on it (the notification is no longer visible in the notification centre) then the *onClose* handler does get called.

As far as I can tell, this problem is unique to Chrome running on Mountain Lion (I haven't tested it on previous versions of OSX but I presume that functions in a similar way to Windows, since the notification centre did not exist then). Using Safari on Mountain Lion, the *onClose* is properly called when dismissing the notification, and it is also called when dismissing the notification from Chrome under Windows.

Does anybody have any idea why this should be so, and if there is some way to correctly receive the *onClose* event?

I have set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AzxC9/) for people to test this.

(Just to clarify, I'm running version 22.0.1229.79 of Chrome, and the test works on version 6.0.1 of Safari).